# How to efficiently create 100's of toggle image buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking for a way to change image A to B and B to A by just 
clicking them.

So far, this is what I'm using.

```
<img id="pixelbutton" src="images/pixelbutton.png" />
<img id="pixelbutton2" src="images/pixelbutton_press.png" style="display: none;" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#pixelbutton").click(function(){
         $("#pixelbutton").css({'display':'none'})
         $("#pixelbutton2").css({'display':'block'});
     })
     $("#pixelbutton2").click(function(){
         $("#pixelbutton2").css({'display':'none'})
         $("#pixelbutton").css({'display':'block'});
     })
})
</script>
```

The script works well for a pair of image.
Now if I have 100 pair of image.

```
"A <--> B" 
"C <--> D"
"E <--> F"
```

and so on...

Do I have to copy the body HTML and script 100 times and change their ID+URL or there is another more efficient way?

Comment: Just making sure... the images will be the same for all 100 or however many you want in right?

Comment: The pairing will be fixed. The image will be different to each other. So If A is already paired with B, image A or B will not be paired with any other image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create hundreds of them... First, use a class.

Then, use a [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attribute to store the "alternate" URL.

```
<img class="pixelbutton" src="images/pixelbutton.png" data-altsrc="images/pixelbutton_press.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".pixelbutton").click(function(){

    // Get the two values
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var altSrc = $(this).data("altsrc");

    // Switch them
    $(this).attr("src",altSrc).data("altsrc",src);
  });
})
</script>
```

This will work for thousands of `.pixelbutton`...
;)

---

**EDIT**

As per this other [`.data()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), (I wonder *why* there's two different documentation pages...) the `data-*` have to be lowercase... Because when trying to get `altSrc`, it is interpreted as `alt-src`.

I just learned that... That is quite a *strange* new standard, from jQuery 3.

So here is [your CodePen updated](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GMZNvx?editors=1111).

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. What did I do wrong? https://codepen.io/Velocodes/pen/MEyjZZ

Comment: Your CodePen didn't have the jQuery lib loaded... But it wasn't just that. See edit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably set a naming pattern and use delegation to make an event handler on the images' container.

You could check if the event's target is an image and retrieve its id. Using that id, you could use the pattern you've set to change the images interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this, but this is by far the simplest approach:

1. Wrap your image pairs in a parent `<div>`
2. Use `.toggleClass()` to toggle a class, say `.hide`, in the images in the element

This solution **assumes that you have images in pairs** :) see proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).siblings());
    $(this).add($(this).siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
/* For layout only */
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Used to hide image */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/b13131/ffffff" class="hide" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $imgBlock = $('#images');
  var html = '';
  var imgArr = [
    'http://i0.wallpaperscraft.com/image/surface_shape_metal_116716_200x300.jpg',
    'http://i0.wallpaperscraft.com/image/universe_space_face_rocket_116714_200x300.jpg',
    'http://i0.wallpaperscraft.com/image/letter_surface_wooden_116674_200x300.jpg',
    'http://i0.wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountains_lake_reflection_116663_200x300.jpg',
    'http://i1.wallpaperscraft.com/image/leaf_drops_surface_116678_200x300.jpg',
    'http://i1.wallpaperscraft.com/image/candle_spruce_christmas_decoration_116684_200x300.jpg'
  ];

  $.each(imgArr, function(index, url) {
    html += (index % 2 === 0) ? '<div>' : '';
    html += '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
    html += (index % 2 === 1 || index === imgArr.length - 1) ? '</div>' : '';

  });

  $imgBlock.append(html);

  $imgBlock.on('click', 'img', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').find('img').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```